# disable hibernate cache for specific query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate (3.6.0) for standard entity mapping as well as a few direct 'statistical' sql queries.

some of these direct queries happen to have the same data 'shape' ie same fields however represent very different pieces of information based on their source table and parameters.

for these i use `SQLQuery.addEntity` using the same bean.

I am using a 'row id' for the `@Id` since the real identifier is a quite complex composite key.

Now since two different queries map to the same bean, hibernate thinks it is clever to cache the results of the first query, and return those results for the second entirely different query.

I have tried to do the following:

1. `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);` at the earliest point in the session
2. `qry.setCacheable(false);` when constructing the query
3. `qry.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);` when constructing the query
4. `@Cacheable(value = false)` as an annotation on the entity object

The only thing I have found that works is to make the entity's `@Id` a string concatenation of both the defining query source table and parameters. This is obviously not ideal.

my question is, if hibernate seems to have so many different ways of telling the engine to ignore the cache, why do none of them work?

and is there a better way to tell hibernate to disable the cache for selected queries while leaving it as per usual for everything else?

Comment: Dear @pstanton I have same issue please write the solution if you found any...

Comment: I create a column in the query by concatenating the columns that make the row unique and map that column to the @Id field.